# How to use BottomSheets to show share dialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-sharing

I want to show one *share via* dialog in my app which shows `Intent.ACTION_SEND` like this [image]

I tried [this library](https://github.com/Stenbergroom/BottomSheet). It works fine , but it uses showDialog() to show the share dialog , which is deprecated. I need the exact style of this share window. Is there any way to implement? Or how can I implement bottomSheets using DialogFragment?

Comment: Can you share a complete working code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but you gave me idea. Look at this https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/styles.xml.

Take whatever you like and put in your styles.xml.

Than do smth like this in your dialog fragment

`@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.BottomSheet_Dialog);
    }`

Comment: What exactly code you are interested in? I have huge open source project https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand. But without pointing out what you want I don't think that would be very useful.

Comment: To get a bottom-sheet share dialog. I'd like it to work from sdk 14 - 23 with the same look